# how to make a jsf @ManagedBean also a @WebService

Tags: java, web-services, jsf, jsf-2, ejb

I want to make a jsf managed bean also a web service simply by adding the @WebService annotation above the class definition, and @WebMethod annotations to the managed beans methods.

This doesn't work, at least not on websphere.

The managed bean's methods are making some EJB calls by invoking methods of injected session beans, for this reason, defining a new web service class and calling the JSF managed bean's methods from its @WebMethods is not working either.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest you to use an approach where the managed bean just keeps the page state, and that it delegates all the transactional stuff to an EJB, so you can expose as web service not the managed bean methods, but the EJB ones.

**update:** this works for me with TomEE+ 1.6.0, is that what you want?

```
package somepackage;
import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;
import javax.jws.WebService;

@ManagedBean
@WebService
@ViewScoped
public class ManagedBeanAndWebService implements Serializable{

    private static final long   serialVersionUID    = 4479173603147480764L;
    private String someAttribute="xyz";

    public String getSomeAttribute() {
        return someAttribute;
    }

    public void setSomeAttribute(String someAttribute) {
        this.someAttribute = someAttribute;
    }

    @WebMethod(operationName="methodName")
    public void someWebMethod(String s){
        System.out.println(s);
    }
}
```

and xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
    xmlns:pe="http://primefaces.org/ui/extensions">
<h:head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>Test</title>
</h:head>
<h:body>

    <h:form id="form">
        <p:outputLabel value="#{managedBeanAndWebService.someAttribute}"/> 
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

and WS

[image]

Comment: I'd normally do that, but there's a specific case of invoking an external application from within the managed bean, and the invoker method also has to be accessible via a web service.